# How to implement Angular4 like dynamic change of components on the screen in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic3

I am trying to implement a dynamic component change in ionic , the way that angular provides with its routing capabilities
for example in angular,
i have a parent component A, inside which there is a component B and C ,
now i wish to change (route) component C to a Component D without changing B and staying in A itself.

In ionic I have tried to use the ionic navCtrl but it changes the whole page and not a single component.
this is easily done in angular using a child router which swaps C for D ,
but how do i replicate the same effect in ionic??
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use *ngIf in this case,
get component B, component C & component D using selectors in component A.

Now use *ngIf to show/hide any of the component.

Ex :

> component-a.ts

`<component-b></component-b>
<component-c *ngIf="somevalue"></component-c>
<component-d *ngIf="!somevalue"></component-d>`